# Can I detect chrome tab crashes from the client machine?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, events, crash

We have a web app that basically runs a slideshow in Chrome.

Sometimes the chrome tab will crash with the "Aw snap" displaying. Chrome stays open.

We're not yet entirely sure what's causing this crash but so far we've been able just to reopen the tab and have things working again.

Is there a way, using .NET, that we can detect these tab crashes?

We are thinking of a program running on the client machine that closes and re-opens the tab in the event of a crash.